# How do I write a query that compares each row of one table to all the rows of a different table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

So I am trying to match an employee's latitude and longitude to the lat-long of a covid containment zone. In my database, I have a table called 'employee' with the columns 'Row_index', 'Address', 'Employee_ID', 'Latitude' and 'Longitude',
and a second table called 'red_zones' with the columns 'Location_index', 'Address', 'Latitude' and 'Longitude'.

Now I have to match the Lat-Long of each employee in the table 'employee' to the Lat-Long of all containment zones in the table 'red-zones'.
I decided to use a stored procedure by iterating through the 'red_zones' table:

```
    BEGIN
        DECLARE i, locationCount INT DEFAULT 0;
        DECLARE lat, lon VARCHAR(45) DEFAULT ' ';
        SELECT COUNT(*) INTO locationCount FROM red_zones;
        WHILE i <= locationCount DO
            SET i = i+1;
            SELECT Latitude INTO lat FROM red_zones WHERE Location_index = i;
            SELECT Longitude INTO lon FROM red_zones WHERE Location_index = i;
            SELECT Employee_ID FROM employee WHERE Latitude = lat AND Longitude = lon;
        END WHILE;
    END
```

After calling the procedure, I got the error 'maximum result count reached, no more results could be displayed'. I figured this was probably because the number of rows in the 'red_zones' table was over 700.

So I decided to Iterate through the 'employee' table instead (26 rows):

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE i, employeeCount INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE lat, lon VARCHAR(45) DEFAULT ' ';
    DECLARE flag INT DEFAULT NULL;
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO employeeCount FROM employee;
    WHILE i <= employeeCount DO
        SET i = i+1;
        SELECT Latitude INTO lat FROM employee WHERE Row_index = i;
        SELECT Longitude INTO lon FROM employee WHERE Row_index = i;
        SELECT Location_index INTO flag FROM red_zones WHERE Latitude = lat AND Longitude = lon;
        IF flag != NULL THEN
            SELECT Employee_ID FROM employee WHERE Row_index = i;
        END IF;
    END WHILE;
END
```

This procedure did not give me any output at all.
I have also made sure that there is a lat-long that matches between the two tables.

Should I be looking to modify my procedures, and if so, in what way?
Or should I be looking at a completely different method of achieving my goal?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not a `join`? Please provide some sample data with expected output.

Comment: I am new to mysql, was not aware of the functionalities a join offers!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why am I not able to achieve the same result through procedures? Since I have only worked with java, the first solution that came to my mind was iterating through all the rows.

Comment: @AarnavShah . . . You need to find someone in your organization who understands databases.  They are quite different from languages such as Java, and much of your intuition will not transfer easily (particularly anything about modularization and procedures).  You should probably also find some tutorials on SQL to learn the basics of the language -- and `JOIN` is a basic part of the language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple `inner join` will give you all the employees who are in redzone.

```
SELECT emp.*
FROM employee emp
JOIN red_zones rz ON emp.Latitude = rz.Latitude
                  AND emp.Longitude = rz.Longitude
```